# PDO - Need to specify bindParam or does assigning them in array work

Tags: php, database, pdo

I have been using the following style code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO contact_messages (fromEmail, message) VALUES (:fromEmail, :message)"; 

// Create bound values
$query_params = array(  
    ':fromEmail' => $contactFrom, 
    ':message' => $contactMessage
); 

try 
{ 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    $return['messageSent'] = true;
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
die
}
```

I thought that this was safe, but just seen i haven't specified that i am binding the parameters? or is what im doing still safe enough?

Also at this point, should I still be using e.g htmlPurifier on the input? or is the PDO bound parameters enough?

Comment: See the documentation - it should be fairly clear. (SQL Injection only occurs when doing *manual query string building with data*.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is still safe but binding parameter is safer.

The difference is when you pass the array to `execute()` all the params are treated as strings.

Whereas when you bind params you are being explicit meaning there is no way to execute with the wrong data type.

Answer (score 0):

`bindParam` is used to pass a reference of the variable to the placeholders. `bindParam` is useful when you run through a **foreach** loop like:

```
foreach ($params as $key => &$val) 
{
    $sth->bindParam($key, $val);
}
```

Notice the ampersand at `&$val`. If you change the variable value after that code, the query will include the new value when you issue `execute` whereas when you use `bindValue` you pass by value directly to the placeholder you've specified in your query so modifying the variable won't affect it anymore.

Also, the way you're doing it directly in `execute` is the same thing as `bindValue`, which means that you're passing by value. The only difference is that you can call `bindValue` and do something before you execute your query.